# Having trouble with hot observable

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I am trying to create two pipelines for each symbol. Each symbol will `Buffer` data based on two timeframes, and perform `DoCalc` on each timeframe.

```
priceChangedObservable = Observable.FromEvent<QuoteChangeEvent, IQuote>(handler =>
    {
        QuoteChangeEvent qHandler = (e) =>
        {
            handler(e);
        };

        return qHandler;
    },
    qHandler => bapi.MAPI.OnQuoteChange += qHandler,
    qHandler => bapi.MAPI.OnQuoteChange -= qHandler
    );
```

If I do as follows:

```
var els = new EventLoopScheduler();
var dispatcher = new EventLoopScheduler();

   var multiCastStream = Observable.Publish(priceChangedObservable);

    int timeFrame = 60;
     multiCastStream
    .GroupBy(instrument => instrument.Symbol)
    .SelectMany(q => q)            
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeFrame))
    .Where(messages => messages.Any())
    .SubscribeOn(els)
    .ObserveOn(dispatcher)
    .Select((sr) => DoCalc(sr, timeFrame))
    .Subscribe((en) => { if (null != en) Console.WriteLine(en); });

    // Start the producer
    multiCastStream.Connect();
```

Everything works as I expect it to. If I **comment out** the above code and add a second timeframe before the `multiCastStream.Connect()` statement:

```
    int secondTimeFrame = 300;
    multiCastStream
    .GroupBy(instrument => instrument.Symbol)
    .SelectMany(q => q)
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondTimeFrame))
    .Where(messages => messages.Any())
    .SubscribeOn(els)
    .ObserveOn(dispatcher)
    .Select((sr) => DoCalc(sr, secondTimeFrame))
    .Subscribe((en) => { if (null != en) Console.WriteLine(en); });
```

That also works as expected. However, if I have **both** codes running, I get **unexpected** behavior.

Is there something fundamental I am missing when sharing `Hot Observables`?

**EDIT 1**

After modifying code with answer from Aron, I get:

```
Number of quotes 1
60: 6/20/2019 10:53:26 PM=> M2KU9 Stats.
Number of quotes 1
300: 6/20/2019 10:53:26 PM=> M2KU9 Stats.
Number of quotes 40
60: 6/20/2019 10:54:26 PM=> MNQU9 Stats.
```

Then, no other stats get printed.

Comment: Is there any reason you need the `Observable.Publish()`? If I am reading this right, you should be able to get rid of `.Publish` completely, and you can get rid of `.SubscribeOn`.

Comment: Well the Publish is to share (multicast) the events as a [Hot] Observable.

Comment: Also, what is your "unexpected behavior". The only thing that might be unexpected, is that the boundaries to the Buffering Windows do not match up, and thus the `DoCalc` boundaries do not match up.

Comment: Unexpected meaning, sometimes I get a result on one and not the other, EVEN though there must be one, since all DoCalc Does is gather stats on quotes that I know are happening before my eyes.

Comment: What makes you think you need publish? Publish is not "multicasting". It is so that multiple subscribers (downstream) can share one single subscription (`bapi.MAPI.OnQuoteChange += qHandler`). You should be able to have multiple EventHandlers (and thus subscriptions) on `bapi.MAPI.OnQuoteChange`.

Comment: You "Unexpected behavior" is completely expected. The two ".Buffer" operations do not start at the same time, they are not synchronize.

Comment: No, I mean one or the other prints every five minutes, or sometimes both do, or sometimes only one prints at one minute and the other doesn't... It is not because they are out of sync, it is that something is wrong.

Comment: They are out of sync. If they are off beat wrt to each other, then there is no obvious correlation to the outputs. The item you expected would be in one 5min bucket, end up in the next bucket because of minor timing differences.

Comment: `priceChangedObservable` is already hot. There's no need for `.Publish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working as expect, your logic is flawed. To demonstrate I shall draw an Rx Marble diagram

```
Quote   -----------x--------------x-----------x-----------x--
Buffer1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
Buffer2   |       |       |       |       |       |       |   
Where 1 ------------x---------------x-----------x-----------x
Where 2 ----------------------------------x-------x-----------
                    ^Notice It seems like there should be an event on 2
                     But there wasn't?
```

Instead, you might was to synchronize these

```
var synchronizationSource = Observerable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
     .Publish()
using(synchronizationSource.Connect())
{
       IObservable<Stat> CreateTimeFrame(int seconds)
       {
           var bufferTimeFrame = synchronizationSource
                         .Where(i => i % seconds == 0);
           return priceChangedObservable
               .GroupBy(instrument => instrument.Symbol)
               .SelectMany(q => q)            
               .Buffer(bufferTimeFrame)
               .Where(messages => messages.Any())
               .ObserveOn(dispatcher)
               .Select((sr) => DoCalc(sr, timeFrame))
       }

       CreateTimeFrame(60)
          .Subscribe((en) => { if (null != en) Console.WriteLine(en); });
       CreateTimeFrame(300)
          .Subscribe((en) => { if (null != en) Console.WriteLine(en); });


       Thread.Sleep(100000);
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps I am not explaining the effect I am expecting. I want to gather quotes every minute and every five minutes on each symbol, and compute stats on each. I tried the code you give, and it doesn't do that. See edit 1 in original post.

Comment: Using your code I was able to make it work. I had to modify it a bit. I will post that later.